# How to mount a damaged internal hard drive in an Ubuntu VM running on Windows 10?

Tags: 18.04, mount, virtualbox, hard-drive

### The Issue

I had a Windows 10 PC whose hard drive went belly up. I'm trying to recover data from it by using an Ubuntu VM through VirtualBox on another Windows 10 PC.

### What I've Done

So far, I have:

1. Installed the damaged hard drive in another PC via a SATA connection.
2. Created an Ubuntu VM in VirtualBox.
3. Failed to figure out how to mount the damaged hard drive in Ubuntu.

When I go to Disk Management on the host, it shows the damaged disk as uninitialized (screenshot below):

[image: Uninitialized disk]

My understanding is that normally to get a drive to display in an Ubuntu VM, one would need to map the physical hard drive to a virtual disk and add that virtual disk to the VM. I haven't been able to find how to do this, and I especially don't know how to do this when Windows doesn't recognize the drive and doesn't assign it a drive letter.

### My Question

Could you please provide step-by-step instructions on how to get my "uninitialized disk" to be mounted/viewable/navigable in my Ubuntu VM? From there, I'm hoping to figure out how to use GNU ddrescue to clone the drive and then TestDisk to extract the data. Thanks!

### Software Versions

I am using **VirtualBox 6.0.0** r127566 (Qt5.6.2) and running an **Ubuntu 18.04.1** LTS VM on a **Windows 10** host.

Comment: For future reference, it might be much easier to simply boot into the "Try Ubuntu" environment of a LiveUSB to conduct your data recovery.

Comment: I thought about that, but I I would like to be able to kick off data recovery in the background and continue working in Windows (the host).